# If $f(x)$ is differentiable, can $1/f$ be locally integrable at a zero of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ be some finite-length interval, let $f : (a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be some (everywhere-)differentiable function.
Suppose $f$ has a zero in its domain.

My question is: In the above case, it possible for $\int_{(a,b)} \frac{dt}{|f(t)|}$ to be *finite*?

For example, this integral is $\infty$ for e.g. $f(t) = |t|^{\alpha-1}t$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\,,\,\alpha\geq 1$, with $(a,b)$ some open interval containing $0$. [If I'm not mistaken this is differentiable with derivative $0$ at $t=0$.]

However, I'm not sure how to approach the more general case, or how to look for a counter-example.

Comment: Hmm, I think probably not. If $f(c)=0,$ then near $c$, $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is close to $\frac{1}{|(x-c)f’(c)|}$ and that won’t be integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(c)=0$ Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(t)|=|f(t)-f(c)| <(1+|f'(c)| |t-c|$ for $|t-c| <\delta$. Now $\int_a^{b}\frac 1 {|f(t)|} dt\geq a\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}\frac 1 {|t-c|} dt$ where $a=(1+|f'(c)|)^{-1}$. It follows that $\int_a^{b}\frac 1 {|f(t)|} dt=\infty$. This uses only the definition of $f'(c)$ and it is not necessary to assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: Thank you! This helps me see very directly how the definition of derivative is used. Also I see now the continuously differentiable assumption (in my earlier comment) is unnecessary.