# Relationship between local non-integrability of $1/f$ and one-sided differentiability of $f$ at a zero

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a,c,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<c<b$.

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of (well-defined pointwise; i.e. *not* modulo almost-everywhere equality) continuous functions $f : [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
such that $f(c) = 0$, and such that $f$ has no zeros other than $c$. (The last condition is just for simplicity. (Though I guess unfortunately this makes $\mathcal{F}$ not closed under linear or even convex combinations.))

- Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all $f\in \mathcal{F}$ for which $\frac{1}{f} \notin L^1([a,b])$, i.e.
  $$
  \int_a^b \frac{dt}{|f(t)|} = \infty\,.
  $$
- Next, let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all $f \in \mathcal{F}$ for which the left- and right-sided derivatives of $f$ at $c$ exist; i.e. the one-sided limits
  $$
  \lim_{h \to 0^{\pm}} \frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h}
  $$
  exist for each sign $\pm$.

---

If I'm not mistaken, the answer posted on my earlier question [If $f(x)$ is differentiable, can $1/f$ be locally integrable at a zero of $f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132470/if-fx-is-differentiable-can-1-f-be-locally-integrable-at-a-zero-of-f) [ credit to the answerer! ] shows that
$$
\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{A} \,.
$$

Here my question is whether the converse $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ is true?
I haven't managed to show this, nor have I found a counter-example.

---

EDIT: I changed the definition of $\mathcal{B}$ (and the title of the question) after I noticed a flaw in the original definition.

Comment: It’s very interesting how you seem to be exploring the quantity $\int 1/f dx$ in relation to derivatives. If you know basic ODE theory like Picard Lindelöf, you would find the Osgood  lemma very interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reverse inclusion is not true.  Let $a=-1$, $b=1$, and $c=0$; and define $$f(x)=x\ln{\!(|x|)}$$ (extended by continuity to $f(0)=0$).  Then $$\int_{-1}^1{\frac{dx}{|f(x)|}}=-2\int_0^1{\frac{dx}{x\ln{\!(x)}}}=-2\int_{-\infty}^0{\frac{du}{u}}=\infty$$  Thus $\frac{1}{|f|}\notin L^1([-1,1])$; and so $f\in\mathcal{A}$.  On the other hand, $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}{\frac{f(h)}{h}}=\lim_{h\to0}{\ln{\!(h)}}=-\infty$$  Thus $f\notin\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: This solves it, thank you!